# How to remove a part substring from a string?

Tags: java

String content = "is not like is, but mistakes are common";

output: "not like , but mistake are common"

desired output: "not like , but mtakes are common"

Comment: Maybe you could show us what you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

```
String result = content.replace("is", "");
```

Comment: This correctly gets OP's **stated** desired result, but I have to wonder if he actually misstated...

Answer (score -1):

```
String string = "your text here test";
string = string.replace(" test", "")
```

String string is now "your text here" instead of "your text here test"